# How to color each glb or fade in expex?

Tags: color, expex

I would like to have less distractive color on each glb. I've already tried to use `color` package. Unfortunately, I'm getting error

> Missing \cr inserted.  \cr l.438 \endgl

If I would replace

```
\lingset{glspace=1em,everygla={},everyglb=\color{halfgray}, glhangstyle=none}
```

with

```
 \lingset{glspace=1em,everygla={},everyglb=\scriptsize, glhangstyle=none})
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: If I remove `,everyglb=\color{halfgray}` I get `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \mainlist` is the error really due to color?

Comment: I've provided demo and exact following code. Without color package everything works fine.

Comment: I've added the important line below main code. You can change it and see working code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If you replace `\color{halfgray}` by `\footnotesize` (for example) it works fine. It seems to be that the *global color declarations* are not accepted.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In `\gla` `\color{...}` is accepted, but in `\glb` doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So... the latex color package tries to make color obey tex grouping even though the underlying mechanism doesn't really use groups. It does this mainly by restoring colour at the end of a group using `\aftergroup`.

As noted in the package documentation this may require an additional brace pair for "color safety" in box assignments and alignments. This package has lots of both, without the extra groups.

Without knowing the package it's a bit hard to patch everything but if you are using pdftex you can use

```
\lingset{glspace=1em,everygla={\pdfliteral{0 g 0 G}},everyglb=\pdfliteral{0.5 g 0.5 G}, glhangstyle=none}
```

To use the underlying color setting, this sets it to grey and you have to explictly set it back to black in the everygla code you might need to set it to black at the end of the environment as well

Comment: [Full color support](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301321/using-color-in-expex-gives-missing-cr-error) is being added to a future version of `expex`.