# Using color in expex gives "Missing \cr" error

Tags: errors, color, linguistics, expex

**Original Question:**
Trying to print one gloss level in `expex` in blue. The following gives me a "Missing \cr inserted" error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{color}
\lingset{everyglc=\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
\ex \begingl
\gla Gloss this//
\glb black gloss//
\glc blue gloss//
\endgl \xe
\end{document}
```

Interestingly, when trying to color the `glb` line, i.e., the second to last gloss line via `\lingset{everyglb=\color{blue}` this works just fine.  I've tried with custom defined gl-levels and it's always whatever the last gloss line happens to be that gives this error. It only happens with color, not with `\bfseries` for instance, or any other declaration.

I'm aware this is the same problem as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204671/how-to-color-each-glb-or-fade-in-expex), but—as opposed to the solution there—I would prefer to define colors the way the `color` package handles colors which I use elsewhere in the document (with the `dvipsnames` option, not in the MWE).

**Update:**

The `expex` developer, John Frampton, has added color functionality <del>to a pre-release version. Those interested in beta-testing should email him for the code.</del> See answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to color each glb or fade in expex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204671/how-to-color-each-glb-or-fade-in-expex)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I just checked, it's indeed the same problem, but I'd much prefer a solution via `color` package. Also, I don't use pdftex as suggested there.  I've edited the question. (Do you think it's still a duplicate?  And, if so, how would I "add" my case to the other question?)

Comment: Ask the author to make the code "color safe".  As it is there is imho neither some suitable hook nor sensible patch to do it.

Comment: I sent him a message.  Will report back if he responds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expex is now "color safe". The developer has kindly added multiple ways of dealing with colors starting with version 5.1.

The `\textcolor` command can now be used anywhere in any of the lines.

An option  `xyzcolor=colorname`, where `"xyz"` is the name of the gloss line (such as `gla`, `glb`, or `glpreamble`) has also been provided whereby an entire line can be set to a given color (for example `[glacolor=red]`), globally or locally.

See below for some fairly self-explanatory examples of use.  (The documentation hasn't been updated yet.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\ex[glccolor=red] 
\begingl
\glpreamble \textcolor{cyan}{Comparison of numerals in various languages.}//
\gla \textcolor{blue}{English} one two three//
\glb \textcolor{blue}{German} ein zwei drei//
\glc \textcolor{blue}{Sanskrit} \'e-ka dv\'a tr\'\i//
\glb \textcolor{blue}{Irish} {a haon} {a d\'o} {a tr\'\i}//
\glft \textcolor{cyan}{This is where a free translation could go, if desired.}//
\endgl
\xe

\ex[glstyle=nlevel,glneveryline=,glspace=1.2em,glnlinecolors={,,red}]
\begingl
\glpreamble  Comparison of numerals in various languages.\endpreamble
\textcolor{blue}{English}[\textcolor{blue}{German}/\textcolor{blue}{Sanskrit}/
   \textcolor{blue}{Irish}]
one[eins/\'e-ka/a haon]
two[zwei/dv\'a/a d\'o]
three[drei/tr\'\i/a tr\'\i]
\glft This is where a free translation could go, if desired.
\endgl
\xe

\lingset{glftpos=right,glneveryline=}

\ex[glspace=1.2em,glccolor=red,everygla=]
Comparison of numerals in various languages.

\bigskip
\begingl
\gla \textcolor{blue}{English} one two three//
\glb \textcolor{blue}{German} ein zwei drei//
\glc \textcolor{blue}{Sanskrit} \'e-ka dv\'a tr\'\i//
\glb \textcolor{blue}{Irish} {a haon} {a d\'o} {a tr\'\i}//
\glft This is where a free translation could go, if desired.//
\endgl
\xe

\ex[glstyle=nlevel,glnlinecolors={,,red}]
Comparison of numerals in various languages.

\bigskip
\begingl[glnlinecolors={red,magenta,blue,green}]
\textcolor{blue}{English} [\textcolor{blue}{German}/\textcolor{blue}{Sanskrit}/   \textcolor{blue}{Irish}]
one[eins/\'e-ka/a haon]
two[zwei/dv\'a/a d\'o]
three[drei/tr\'\i/a tr\'\i]
\glft \textcolor{orange}{This is where a free translation could go, if desired.}
\endgl
\xe

\end{document}
```